# Insert multiple dummy Records depending on a certain value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have to create a table that shows an installment plan.
The initial table that I have, only shows the basic data, with one record for one contract. F. e. we have a 48 Months term.
That would mean I have to create 48 recordsets that shows how the principal amount and some more values are changing during the life span of 48 months.

So at the end for every contract I should show n records, while n is the number of months.

I thought I do that with a second table, with the contract number as a foreign key. And insert the details records depending on the number of months.
In this way I would crate a one to many relationship.

So the question is now, how to create the exact number of records for every contract-record depending on the number of month of each contract?

Comment: You start by providing us with some details. Sadly what you posted is just not clear what you want here. This would be a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Google search: "SQL Calendar Table" and that should hopefully get you started. If not, as Sean Lange said, we are going to need more info to help.

Comment: Sorry for the vague question. Maybe my english is a bit limited.

Answer (score 0):

You should to create and store a number table.  EG

```
create table N(i int primary key)
go
with q as
(
  select row_number() over (order by(select null)) i
  from sys.objects, sys.columns c,sys.columns c2
)
insert into N(i)
select top 10000 i
from q

go


select c.id, N.i MonthNumber, . . .
from contracts c
join N
  on n.i between 1 and c.ContractTerm
```

Answer (score 0):

For just 48 you could hard code them.

```
declare @month table (mm tinyint not null primary key)
INSERT INTO @month (mm)
VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12);

declare @contract table (name varchar(10), term tinyint not null) 
INSERT INTO @contract (name, term)
VALUES ('four',  4),
       ('eight', 8);

select c.name, m.mm 
  from @contract c 
  join @month m 
    on m.mm <= c.term  
order by c.name, m.mm
```